# Troubleshooting international SIM connection issues on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, network, cellular-data, sim

I have an iPhone SE 2 with a German O2 SIM card with an unlimited data plan and that is supposed to be able to use other networks when traveling in the EU. The last time I was in Sweden it often worked well and then there were totally unpredictable periods where it went down for a bit, anywhere from a few hours to days, then came back. During that time the phone might appear to be connected, showing full bars and LTE, but webpages never load. It looks like the phone thinks it’s connected but when it makes a request it never gets a response, not even an error one.

I have checked stuff like mobile data being on, data roaming, if my cell phone bills are paid, and also talking to some cell phone network representatives. I would like to know how I can investigate the connection under the hood with commands to know where in the system the issue really is.

Can I plug my iPhone into my Mac and somehow run command line commands to test the cell network in different ways, checking for confirmation that it is connected to the network, and trying to see specifically that a request went out and there is no response? Then I could know that it might be the Swedish networks that aren’t serving the number at that moment for some reason. Or, that it’s something else.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot plugin your iPhone into your Mac in order to run command line commands to test the cell network in different ways.

In the scenario you describe, the cell network provider did not or could fulfil your data requests. There could be many different reasons for that - most of them not detectable by your phone.

In case it happens again, just roam onto a different provider's network - or move to a location with better cell coverage.